# jQuery - escape CSS and HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, escaping, textarea

I'm currently building a live CSS & HTML editor.
CSS is appended in style tag while the user is typing in a textarea.
And the HTML is output in a DOM element thanks .hml($custom_html) when the user type HTML in a textarea.

I'm currently using these functions to escape CSS and HTML in order to prevent code injection and to have something completly safe:

```
function CSS(input) {

    return input.replace(/<script[^>]*?>.*?<\/script>/gi, '').
                    replace(/<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>/gi, '').
                    replace(/<style[^>]*?>.*?<\/style>/gi, '').
                    replace(/<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>/gi, '');

};


function HTML(input) {

    return input.replace(/<script[^>]*?>.*?<\/script>/gi, '').
                    replace(/<script[^>]*?>/gi, '').
                    replace(/<\/script[^>]*?>/gi, '').
                    replace(/<style[^>]*?>/gi, '').
                    replace(/<\/style[^>]*?>/gi, '').
                    replace(/<style[^>]*?>.*?<\/style>/gi, '');

};
```

I'm not an expert for escaping and in security. So, I would like to know if my jQuery functions will prevent from security vunerability?

Comment: Does any information get saved to a DB or elsewhere when using the editor?

Comment: These values are saved in a BD but everything is sanitzed and escaped before inserting. There isn't any issue from this side. My issue is with the live html and css code in the browser.

Comment: If everything is sanitized going in then coming out it should be clean.  If the user injects code they will only be affecting themselves and not anyone else (assuming it is actually sanitized when saved).